# На сколько длинную строку можно задать через sys.argv?

Tags: python

Используя модуль sys.argv, на сколько максимально символов можно создавать строку? Понимаю что выглядеть это будет не очень, но как себя вообще будет чувствовать питон если в аргумент после скрипта передать строку в 100 000 символов?

Comment: Максимальная длина аргументов ограничена на стороне операционной системы (в windows около 32 тысяч символов, в линуксе около 128 тысяч)

Comment: А питону пофигу, ну будет лежать в списке длинная строка, ну и пусть лежит никого не трогает

Comment: Вот обрабатывать такую строку может быть тяжеловато )